# Deleting All objects(Grouped/Ungrouped) from Canvas with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to remove all the objects on my Canvas without selecting them. The objects in the Canvas include Grouped and Ungrouped object. All the Examples I've seen demonstrate how to delete a single ungroup object.

```
Canvas.ForEachObject(function(o){
     o.remove();
    });
```

Please see the fiddle for an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
https://jsfiddle.net/Shane00711/r8su3ya0/

Comment: I figured it out. So I first retrieve all the object inside the canvas and then I loop through that list of objects(grouped and ungrouped) delete one each time.  var r = canvas.getObjects();

        while (r.length != 0) {
            canvas.remove(r[0]);
            canvas.discardActiveGroup();
        }

Answer (score 30):

Did you know that canvas.remove can take more than one parameter?
So the easiest way should be this one:

```
canvas.remove(...canvas.getObjects());
```

Other than canvas.clear this will only remove the objects in the canvas and not also the background.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for... remove only objects but not background

Answer (score 13):

You just need to call

`canvas.clear()`

it will remove all object

Comment: What I noticed with canvas.clear() is that it clears all the objects and the canvas properties as well i.e( canvas background colour). which is not what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @SifisoMfeya you can store your color property and again init to canvas

Comment: @SifisoMfeya here is your update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/r8su3ya0/10/)

Answer (score -3):

I figured out what I need to do in order to delete every object(grouped/ungrouped) from my Canvas.
First I had to get all the objects in the canvas.

```
var obj = canvas.getObjects();
```

once I got all the objects I simply had to loop through them removing each one as I did.

```
canvas.remove(obj[0]).
```

The reason I reference the index 0 in my

```
canvas.remove(obj[0])
```

is because every time and object was removed from the canvas the number of object in the list 'obj' also decreased by 1, moving all the objects up by 1 index. which meant that every object on my canvas would at some point be at index 0 of the 'obj' list.

here's a fiddle of a working example. where I delete all objects on the canvas without selecting a single one.
http://jsfiddle.net/Shane00711/r8su3ya0/8/

Comment: This method isn't efficient if you have a lot of objects